# Почему mysqli_num_rows() всегда возвращает 0 на IPhone?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, ios, iphone

**Возникает проблема при работе PHP кода.**

Есть скрипт, который вытаскивает из бд данные, проводит с ними простые операции и передает массив назад. Сам скрипт запускается посредством AJAX`a. На всех устройствах, кроме тех что на IOS всё работает как должно.

На айфонах запрос в бд не срабатывает и по итогу mysqli_num_rows() возвращает всегда 0 и ничего другого.

Подскажите в чем ошибка? Возможно есть какая-то особенность или я что-то упустил в запаре. Спасибо.

**JS**

```
    function loadbag(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions/loadbag.php",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                if($(window).width() > 770){
                    document.getElementById("bag-point").innerHTML = ' ' + data.main;//$().html(data.main);
                } else if(data.alt !== null){
                    document.getElementById("bag-point").innerHTML = ' ' + data.alt;//$().html(data.alt);
                }  else if(data.alt === null){
                    $("#bag-point").empty();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

---

```
$('body').on('click', '.add-to-bag', function(){
        var size = $('.size-circle:checked + .size-label').attr('value');
        var color = $('.color-circle:checked + .color-label').attr('value');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var children = $('#data').children().length;

        if(children === 0){
            size = '';
            color = '';
        } else if(children == 1){
            if($('#data :first-child').hasClass('item-size')){
                color = '';
            } else if($('#data :first-child').hasClass('item-color')){
                size = '';
            }
        }
        if(color !== undefined && size !== undefined){ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "functions/addtobag.php",
                data: {id: id, size: size, color: color},
                dataType: "text",
                cache: false
            });
            loadbag();
        } else {
            alert('Выберете размер и цвет');
        }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    include "connect.php";
    include 'word.php';

    $vector = [];
        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT bag_count, bag_price FROM bag WHERE bag_ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $count = $count + $row["bag_count"];
                $total = $total + ($row["bag_count"] * $row["bag_price"]);
            };
            $main = ' '.$count.' '.wordform($count, 'Товар', 'Товара', 'Товаров').' / '.$total.' €';
        } else {
            $main = ' Корзина пуста';
        }

        $vector['main'] = $main;
        $vector['alt'] = $count;
        echo json_encode($vector);
}?>
```

Comment: Корзина храниться по ip ... Это что то новенькое. Во первых ip у пользователя может неожиданно измениться (многие провайдеры у которых динамическая выдача адресов меняют ip раз в час или с другой периодичностью). Во вторых часть провайдеров выпускают в интернет сотни и даже тысячи пользователей под одним и тем же ip

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за советы, однако моя проблема не связана с этим. С любым типом ip, происходит одно и тоже. Функция loadbag() срабатывает, только когда $(document).ready(). В остальных случаях она вызывается по клику и на IOS устройствах проверка на количество строк всегда 0.